# CSS grid container does not use whole width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a simple dashboard in D3.js and vanilla JS. It looks like the image below. I have added a border to make it easier to visualize how I have designed it. The problem is that I want the grid to use the whole width. Now there is a big margin space on the left and the right of the container that I want to reduce (the drawing). Is there an easy way to do this?

I couldn't find any information on this on https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid_container.asp.

[image]

```js
const height = 500;
const width = 800;
const skierIconSvg = 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/94/94150.svg';
const gate =
    'https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/e/2PACX-1vReBMnm0oMHA-DuF_s6ds4irdAl_Y_zSbW3rO3DzG6u2Gmp2_ta2tFXO-poCOm7wXx02Dzd2EsT0c13/pub?w=186&h=290';
const finish =
    'https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/e/2PACX-1vTWOmvwPIu2MrEbZAla5m2N5CcPVsPSEKHeKBI0sZsF9wKkMhZosnOmgMo1WHTnnAPA9i5LV0p0LR_r/pub?w=186&h=290';

const [p1, p2, p3] = [
    [80, 100],
    [750, 230],
    [750, 230],
];

const svg = d3
    .select('#container')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('viewBox', `0 0 800 240`);

// Store a reference to the span we're going to update
const skierHeight = d3.select('#skier-height');

const vek = document.querySelector('#vekt');
console.log(vek.value);

const line = svg.append('line').attr('stroke', 'black');

const connection = svg.append('line').attr('stroke', 'green');

const marker = svg
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', 5)
    .attr('stroke', 'red')
    .attr('fill', 'none');

const g = svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('cursor', 'move')
    .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
    .attr('stroke', 'transparent')
    .attr('stroke-width', 30);

const start = g
    .append('image')
    .attr('id', 'sdjjjjj')
    .datum(p1)
    .attr('href', gate)
    .attr('width', 100)
    .attr('height', 100)
    .call(
        d3
            .drag()
            .subject(([x, y]) => ({
                x,
                y,
            }))
            .on('drag', dragged)
    );

const mal = g
    .append('image')
    .attr('id', 'sdjj')
    .datum(p2)
    .attr('href', finish)
    .attr('width', 100)
    .attr('height', 100)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(710, 140)')
    .call(
        d3
            .drag()
            .subject(([x, y]) => ({
                x,
                y,
            }))
            .on('drag', dragged)
    );

const skier = g
    .append('image')
    .attr('id', 'skier')
    .datum(p3)
    .attr('href', skierIconSvg)
    .attr('width', 100)
    .attr('height', 100)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(-50, -70)')
    .call(
        d3
            .drag()
            .subject(() => ({
                // Use where the skier is, not where he's supposed to be
                x: Number(skier.attr('x')),
                y: Number(skier.attr('y')),
            }))
            .on('start', () => {
                // Interrupt all transitions
                skier.interrupt();
                connection.interrupt();
                marker.interrupt();
            })
            .on('drag', dragged)
            .on('end', dropSkier)
    );

update();

function dragged(d) {
    d[0] = d3.event.x;
    d[1] = d3.event.y;
    update();
    potensiellEnergi();
}

function update() {
    const t = (width + height) / distance(p1, p2);

    const l1 = interpolate(p1, p2, t);

    const l2 = interpolate(p2, p1, t);
    const p = interpolate(p1, p2, project(p1, p2, p3));

    connection.attr('x1', p3[0]).attr('y1', p3[1]);
    connection.attr('x2', p[0]).attr('y2', p[1]);
    marker.attr('cx', p[0]).attr('cy', p[1]);
    line.attr('x1', l1[0]).attr('y1', l1[1]);
    line.attr('x2', l2[0]).attr('y2', l2[1]);
    start.attr('cx', (d) => d[0]).attr('cy', (d) => d[1]);
    skier.attr('x', (d) => d[0]).attr('y', (d) => d[1]);
    mal.attr('cx', (d) => d[0]).attr('cy', (d) => d[1]);

    skierHeight.text(`${getHeight(p, p1, p2).toFixed(2)} meter`);
}
function distance([x1, y1], [x2, y2]) {
    return Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2);
}

function interpolate([x1, y1], [x2, y2], t) {
    return [x1 + (x2 - x1) * t, y1 + (y2 - y1) * t];
}

function project([x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3]) {
    const x21 = x2 - x1,
        y21 = y2 - y1;
    const x31 = x3 - x1,
        y31 = y3 - y1;
    return (x31 * x21 + y31 * y21) / (x21 * x21 + y21 * y21);
}

function getHeight([xp, yp], [x1, y1], [x2, y2]) {
    // Note that y is counted from top to bottom, so higher y means
    // a point is actually lower.

    // First, the total height is 100 metres.
    const pxPerMeter = (y2 - y1) / 100;

    // Calculate the height diff in pixels
    const heightDiffPx = y2 - yp;

    // Now transform it to meters
    return heightDiffPx / pxPerMeter;
}

function vektVelger() {
    const vektVerdi = document.querySelector('#vekt');
    const vektDisplay = document.querySelector('#skier-vekt');

    vektDisplay.innerHTML = vektVerdi.value;
}

function potensiellEnergi() {
    const vektVerdi = parseInt(document.querySelector('#skier-vekt').textContent);
    const skierHeight = parseInt(
        document.querySelector('#skier-height').textContent
    );
    const hastighet = document.querySelector('#skier-hastighet');
    const potEDisplay = document.querySelector('#skier-potentialenergi');
    const potEnergi = `${Math.round(vektVerdi * skierHeight * 9.8)}`;
    const hastighetsutregning = `${Math.round(
        Math.sqrt(2 * (skierHeight * 9.8))
    )}`;
    return (hastighet.innerHTML = `${hastighetsutregning}`)(
        (potEDisplay.innerHTML = `${potEnergi}`)
    );
}

function dropSkier(d) {
    const projection = interpolate(p1, p2, project(p1, p2, p3));
    skier
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        // First down to the ground
        .attr('x', projection[0])
        .attr('y', projection[1])
        .on('end', () => {
            skier
                .transition()
                .duration(2500)
                .ease(d3.easeQuadIn)
                // First down to the ground
                .attr('x', p2[0])
                .attr('y', p2[1]);
        });

    // Remove the line together with the skier
    connection
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        // First down to the ground
        .attr('x1', projection[0])
        .attr('y1', projection[1]);

    marker.transition().duration(700).remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>

        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@300&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC:wght@700&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        />


        <style>
            body {
                background-color: white;
                margin: 1px;
                font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
            }

            .container {
                color: black;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                display: grid;
                grid-gap: 2px;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
                grid-template-rows: 40px auto auto auto;
                grid-template-areas:
                    'h h h h h h h h h h h h'
                    'b b b r r r r r r r r r'
                    'f f f f f f f f f f f f';
            }
            .container div {
                display: flex;
                width: 100%;

                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                color: black;
            }

            .header {
                grid-area: h;
            }

            .bib {
                grid-area: b;
                background-color: white;
                font-size: 1.6em;
                border-style: solid;
            }


            .resultat {
                grid-area: r;
                font-size: 1em;
            }
            .resultat {
                justify-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
            }
            .footer {
                grid-area: f;
                border-style: solid;
                font-size: 1.2EM;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <h1>Forsøk på å lage en tutorial i JavaScript og D3.js</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="bib">
                <p>Denne interaktive visualiseringen regner ut den estimerte hastigheten en
                    utøver har i mål ved å kjøre rett ned bakken med utgangspunkt i
                    høydeforskjell mellom utøverens lokasjon og mål og utøverens vekt.
                    Estimeringen tar ikke hensyn til energi som går med til anvendte krefter,
                    dvs. luftmotstand eller friksjon. Høydeforskjellen justerer du ved å ved
                    dra skikjøreren opp og ned bakken, mens vekten bestemmer du i meyen under
                    figuren.</p>
                <br />
            </div>
            <div class="resultat">
                <div id="container"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer"><form class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputName2">Velg vekt</label>
                    <input
                        type="number"
                        class="form-control input-lg"
                        id="vekt"
                        placeholder="Velg vekt"
                    />
                </div>
                <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-default btn-lg"
                    value="velg"
                    onclick="vektVelger()"
                >
                    Velg
                </button>
            </form><table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Høydeforskjell:</td>
                    <td><span id="skier-height"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Vekt:</td>
                    <td><span id="skier-vekt">70</span> kg</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gravitasjonskraft (fg):</td>
                    <td><span id="skier-gravitasjon">9.8</span> m/sek/sek</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tilgjengelig potensiell energi:</td>
                    <td><span id="skier-potentialenergi">0</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hastighet i mål:</td>
                    <td><span id="skier-hastighet">0</span> m/sek</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            </div>


</div>
        <script src="skier.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.container { ...; margin: 0; padding:0; }`?

Comment: Yes, that reduces the margin on the left side. But still there is margin on the right. I guess there must be another solution but I might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding you want to remove the space from the left and right. Space is caused by the `max-width` in the bootstrap since it won't allow the `container` to go outside a specific range. so if you want to extend you should either remove the `max-width` or use `container-fluid` instead.

```
.container {
        max-width: unset;
    }
```

If that didn't help let me know.

Comment: Cheers. Now I understand the error. The max-width was set by the bootstrap. I removed it and now it works. The max-width: unset; also worked.